# tikz package for drawing thermodynamic cycles

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a extension of tikz library that allows one to draw thermodynamic cycles easily? For example the picture you see in the link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot_heat_engine#mediaviewer/File:Carnot_heat_engine_2.svg

If there is no library can someone suggest a easy way to go about this? Maybe provide an example? I have used LaTeX for a little over a year now but am just starting to draw in LaTeX with tikz.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one possibility where `pic` with 3 arguments, known as nodea, nodeb and nodec are designed here -- #1=color, #2=label and #3=internal node label.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\tikzset{%
pics/.cd,
nodea/.style args={#1#2#3}{
  code={\node[minimum height=2cm] (#3) {\color{#1}#2};
       \draw[thick] (#3.south west) -| (#3.north east)--(#3.north west);
  }
},
%pics/.cd,
nodeb/.style args={#1#2#3}{
  code={\node[minimum height=2cm] (#3) {\color{#1}#2};
       \draw[thick] (#3.south east) -| (#3.north west)--(#3.north east);
  }
},
%pics/.cd,
nodec/.style args={#1#2#3}{
  code={\node[draw,thick,shape=circle,inner sep=1cm] (#3) {\color{#1}#2};
  }
},
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \pic at (0,0) {nodea={red}{$T_H$}{L}};
    \pic at (2,0) {nodec={black}{}{C}};
    \pic at (4,0) {nodeb={blue}{$T_C$}{R}};
 \draw[->,>=latex](L)--node[midway,above]{$\mathbf{Q_H}$}(C); 
 \draw[->,>=latex](C)--node[midway,above]{$\mathbf{Q_C}$} (R);
 \draw[->,>=latex](C)--node[midway,left]{$\mathbf{W}$} ++(0,-2cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just the kind of example I needed to learn how to do the problem.

Comment: Glad, it is an example you need. Welcome.

Comment: +1: It seems you have learned fast the `pic` operation :)

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use pic, following experts advices here

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution with PSTricks just for fun.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[shortput=nab](-4,-3)(4,1)
    \cnode{1}{c}
    \pnode(-3,0){l}\pnode(3,0){r}\pnode(0,-3){b}
    \rput(l){\psline(-1,-1)(0,-1)(0,1)(-1,1)}
    \rput{180}(r){\psline(-1,-1)(0,-1)(0,1)(-1,1)}
    \psset{arrows=->}
    \ncline{l}{c}^{$Q_H$}\ncline{c}{r}^{$Q_C$}\ncline{c}{b}_{$W$}
    \uput[180](l){\color{red}$T_H$}\uput[0](r){\color{blue}$T_C$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]